# Google appengine sdk jar file is missing in staging directory when deploy my app

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

When I try to deploy my application, JSP compilation error is happened since updating new sdk - 1.9.2 .

So I trace this and find the reason.
When I got jsp compilation error during deploying, I checked in the **WEB-INF/lib of the staging directory**.
**Appengine SDK jar file is missing** on there.

I think that is the main reason to make a jsp compilation error.

Please help how to fix this situation.

Comment: I checked appengine tools source code in google code. sdk api jar file is not copied to staging directory. so this is correct behavior. but still my app is failed to compile to JSP!..orz.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, look in your Problems tab. You may see a warning their about the SDK files missing. Right-click, select QuickFix, and choose "Synchronize SDK..." option.

Alternatively, you can remove App Engine SDK from your project and then add it back. It should add the missing files to the `/lib` directory.

Comment: Thx. but my question is related when deploy time on console. not in eclipse.

Comment: OK, forget Eclipse. Just put the missing files in the /war/WEB-INF/lib directory.